# How to pass the same Dash component to both pattern-matching and regular callback?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I've been searching for a solution for hours but nothing came up. The pattern-matching callback expect a `dictionary` as the first argument:

```
Input({'type': 'filter-dropdown', 'index': ALL}, 'value')
```

unlike regular callback which expects a `str`:

```
Input('id-name', 'value')
```

How should I name a component's id property to be able to pass it to both types of callbacks?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just provide the dictionary based ID without using `MATCH` or `ALL`, e.g. `Input({'type': 'filter-dropdown', 'index': 5}, 'value')`